# Trigger jquery when specific list item has active class with specific href inside list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do a jQuery check when the third tab gets active by getting the class `acrive`. But I can't get the jQuery to trigger.

This is a small sample html;

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab2</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Only when `<a href="#tab-3">'s` parent `li` get class `active` something should happen, but I can't get it to work;

This what I tried with jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var onTabThree = jQuery("ul li.active>a[href='#tab-3']");

    if (onTabThree) {
        do_check();
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this working example. in if condition just add `onTabThree.length`.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var onTabThree = jQuery("ul li.active > a[href='#tab-3']");

    if (onTabThree.length) {
        alert("is it working");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab2</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will this also trigger when the class `active` gets added dynamically to tab 3?